# what are they saying? (listening comprehension)

Tags: listening-comprehension

I'm studying a German drama and I couldn't hear what they are saying in this clip.
I have the subtitle but a part of it I am not sure if is correct.
And I became curious if native Germans can really hear it easily.
So please pardon me my putting the clip here to see native Germans can hear it. (I believe you can). What are they saying? (they are in a boat race). It's a very short clip.

https://clyp.it/yidwdgnj

ADD : I have selected an answer below. Just for your information, this clip was from the "Die Susanne" on youtube. (time 01:21:06 ~ 01:21:14)

Comment: It would be easier without the music and noises, I'd say - especially the first person talking is hard to understand due to the other noises.

Comment: @Chan Kim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFFbo8pX2rs One of the commenters identified the distorted speech track on that music video as one of Hitler's speeches.

Comment: @Janka yeah,it sounds like it. I can identify the voice.

Comment: Then, you are better than me. I had only understood the very last sentence fragment. About the voice, that's what blaring in German generally sounds like, and the scratches are from the poor quality of the original recording, I think. It was done on a literal wire, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Link zur Video-Quelle wie oben angegeben: https://youtu.be/1SaSfdKcbkc?t=1h21m6s

Comment: @mtwde Ah, that's a good method. I'll use it next time in this kind of question if I have another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

native speaker here.
I had to replay the beginning three times to get it, because the music is so loud.

> female voice: "Wenn du mich gelassen hättest, dann hätten wir jetzt gewonnen"
>  male voice: "Du kannst doch nicht immer haben was du willst"
>  female voice: "Wo?" << unclear
>  male voice: "Wir sehen uns am Ziel"

Comment: I found not only the music but especially the clipping extremely unhelpful.

Comment: Wow, I envy you natives :) This is interesting. Some mis-hearing : dann hätten wir jetzt geworden ==> dann hätten wir jetzt gewonnen. Wo? ==> Guck!  I select your answer because even though you missted `gewonnen`, you got `doch nicht` which was the most curious part to me, compared to nagnag's answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @Janka I understand. because they can't get the context. If it were a video, they would know it better.

Comment: The piece the girl at the beginning said was completely scratched. Maybe you need to be **impaired** in hearing high frequencies so the scratch isn't bothering you.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is really hard to hear but if I got it correctly, it is: "Wenn du mich gelassen hättest, hätten wir jetzt gewonnen." - Kind of a passive aggressive statement which roughly translates to "If you had let me [done sth.], we would've won!"

The answer to that is: "Du kannst halt nicht immer haben, was du willst." - fairly straightforward, translates to "You can't always get what you want."

Then comes something incomprehensible, just one word or something that I can't understand for the life of me. And the final sentence is: "Wir sehen uns am Ziel!" - this is, from what I can get out of the intonation, a bit of mocking/banter and translates to "See you at the finish line!"

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! your were also almost correct except the `doch nicht` and `Guck!` part. Please see my comment to squiddle's answer. Again Vielen dank!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! The "doch" vs. "halt" in that sentence don't really make a huge difference in my opinion, at least in the sense of the sentence. It gives the sentence a ever-so-slightly different undertone but it doesn't change anything in the "grand scheme of things". And the "Wo?" and "Guck!" were completely incomprehensible to me, maybe I could've figured it out with video material or something, but just by listening it's very hard - as the others stated as well. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: yeah, I understand watching video will make you guess correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ich hör' am Angang was ganz Anderes :-))
"Wenn du mich gelassen hättest, wär'n wir jetzt in Bonn."